# Missing Jenkins functions inside loaded groovy class

Tags: jenkins, groovyclassloader

I am loading external groovy class file using evaluate

```
readTrusted("class_file.groovy")
```

everything is working fine untill I am running jenkins pipeline functions like `dir()` or `checkout()`
then I am getting.

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: 
GitOps.checkout() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) 
values: [[$class:GitSCM, branches:[[name:master]], extensions:[[$class:LocalBranch], ...], ...]]
```

I tried different methods of loading class file nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so my friend found an answer in https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#accessing-steps at the constructor level we needed to add a reference using this to the pipeline script and refer the plugin variables using that reference